# Image wrap with float doesnt work right

Tags: html, css

I was googling hard but still didnt manage to find smth.

Here's the code:

```
          <div class="SingleNewsMain" news-type = "{$value.news_type_id}" >

                    <div class="NewsTitleMain">
                        <a href= "index.php?show_news={$value.id}"><!--{$value.title}-->Some random header</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="NewsMainImage">
                        <a href="#">
                            <img src="img/13095.png">
                        </a>    
                    </div>  

                    <div class="NewsMainShort"> 
                        <!--{$value.short_text}-->
                        Some random description
                    </div>

                    <div class="NewsInfo">
                            <span>
                            <icon class="icon-eye-open"></i>
                            </span>
                            <span class="ViewsInfo">2100</span>                         

                            <span>
                            <icon class="icon-comment"></i>
                            </span>
                            <span class="CommentaryInfo"> 46</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

And here's my CSS

```
.SingleNewsMain{
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(175,175,175);
}
.NewsTitle {
  font-size: 24px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  line-height: 27px;
  font-family: 'Playfair Display SC';
}

.NewsTitleMain {
  font-size: 24px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  line-height: 25px;
  font-family: 'Playfair Display SC';
}

.NewsMainImage{
  padding: 10px 10px 5px 0px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 110px;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
}
.NewsMainShort {
  font-size: 14px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  position: relative;
}
```

And also two screenshots, the **first** one. `.NewsMainShort` has the property `clear:both`

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/833/x7cp.png/

And the **second** one, `.NewsMainShort` doesn't have the property `clear:both`

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/96/jl29.png/

I want the text simply to wrap around the image without the looking like on the **second screenshot**.
Inspect Element in Chrome shows, that when without the `clear:both` the image's DIV doesn't fit the `SingleNewsMain`'s height.

Comment: An image of what you really want?

Comment: I can't get your point. I want the div's height to be determined by the image's height if the DESCRIPTION_TEXT is smaller than the IMAGE's height and by the DESCRIPTION_TEXT's height if the text is higher than the IMAGE. I want it to look like here http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/28/ecyu.png/

Comment: Please don't use caps  <----> It's better if you can reproduce your problem with a Fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to kepp css like in 2nd screenshot, but add after:

```
<div class="NewsMainShort"> 
                    <!--{$value.short_text}-->
                    Some random description
                </div>

<br style="clear:both;">
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked, but why didnt it work when I applied `clear: both` on the  `.NewsMainShort`. And is this valid html?